# List child terms according to parent term page

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I created a view listing all parent terms  and child terms in my site. Following those suggestions:
[Tiered HTML lists using Views and Taxonomy?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/tiered-html-lists-using-views-and-taxonomy)

Now, I need to make the list of child terms change automatically according to the parent term page. For example: 
In the parent term page: Fruits,
This view will show a only a list of those terms:

- Bananas
       Apple
       ….

In the parent term  page: Colors,
This view will show only a list of Colors child terms:

- Red 
       Green
       Yellow

Any Idea how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Drupal 7, I accomplished this by creating a view (for a block) that uses the contextual filter, "Taxonomy term: Parent term" - Under "When the Filter is Not Available" choose "Provide default value", then select "Taxonomy term ID from URL", and check "Load default filter from term page". I then displayed the block on the taxonomy pages where I want the child term lists to appear.

I'm just starting to work with Drupal and I suspect that there's a more robust solution - this works with pathauto but has trouble with terms that use a URL alias - but the instructions I've found for other approaches either don't work or require considerable coding. If you devise a better way, or somebody else has ideas, I'm all ears.

Comment: Thank Aaron, I'm using now Taxonomy menu, and  Block menu to accomplish this, However, I will try your method.

Comment: I had an issue with this method, once you select for example : apple. the views Fruit is not any more visible.
I want the views fruit to show always when selecting any of its terms.

Comment: This is a great way to do it! (especially considering View will be apart of the Drupal 8 core)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to accomplish this, without using views.

1. I have used Taxonomy menu to display a list of all my terms.
2. Then, I used  a nice module called: [Menu block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) , to achieve exactly
   what I want.  It can display a list of parent terms, and then
   display the second level of terms or deeper when you visit one of
   the parent terms page.

Hope this can help someone.